# SQLite concatenate columns / Gephi

Tags: sql, sqlite

Good Morning,

I'm using Gephi to graph some data.
I need a table containing nodes.

For exemple the following table :

```
Surname|Name|Age
Paul|Martin|18
Jean|Eude|24
```

I would like to graph Surname and Age, my nodes request have to return the following result :

```
Nodes
Paul
Jean
18
24
```

The question is how can i concatenate those two columns in one with sqlite ? Should be easy, without function for Gephi.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two queries to select Surname and Age with `Union All` keyword

```
select surname from users
union all
select age from users
```

Sample here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/77WgusrU97Wtgs1oTB49dg/0 for MySQL, but its the same on SQLite

You may add "order by" statement in both queries